# Django filtering twice nested instances

Tags: django

Here is an example of my models:

```
class Section(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Album(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   model1 = models.ManyToManyField(Section, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
 related_name='model2')



class Image(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
   model2 = models.ManyToManyField(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
related_name='model3')
```

I am trying to find all sections which have albums which have images who has active field = False

```
Section.object.filter(albums__images__active=False)
```

But I am getting all images even if their field active=True

Comment: What about this ? `Model1.objects.filter(model2__isnull=False, model2__model1__isnull=False, model2__model3__active=False)`

Comment: Your query doesn't mention `Model3` anywhere. Using made up names like `Model1` makes it harder to understand your question.

Comment: @Alasdair fixed that typo

Comment: I don't understand your comment *I am getting all instances of model3* - your queryset is returning instances of `Model1`, not `Model3`. You're still using made up names that make it difficult to visualise your models.

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge there was a typo in my filter request,  check updated request please

Comment: @Alasdair I'll change names for better understanding

Comment: @Alasdair check it please

Comment: You question *still* contains `model2` and `model3`. And as I said before, I don't understand your comment *I am getting all images even if their field active=True* - your queryset returns sections, not images.